# Twitter API 1.1 GET/favorites/list.json Works For A Short Period Then Stops Working?

Tags: api, twitter

please see my code below. Baically it works and I retreive what I need but only for ashort period and then it stops working. I am wnating ot use the returned data to create a Twitter feed. Can this not be one this way?

```
$oauth_consumer_key = '-------------------';
$oauth_consumer_key_secret = '-------------------';
$oauth_token = '-------------------';
$oauth_token_secret = '-------------------';
$oauth_nonce = '-------------------';
$oauth_signature = '-------------------';
$oauth_timestamp = time();

$oauth_hash = '';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_consumer_key=9bSWNyMCJ2Pu5VOibPU13A&amp;';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_nonce='.$oauth_nonce.'&amp;';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&amp;';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_timestamp='.$oauth_timestamp.'&amp;';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_token=559439614-4cmIUCxb9FfUBsNTmeHZrox2FRpVQbvuED508lQm&amp;';
$oauth_hash .= 'oauth_version=1.0';

$base = '';
$base .= 'GET';
$base .= '&amp;';
$base .= rawurlencode('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json');
$base .= '&amp;';
$base .= rawurlencode($oauth_hash);

$key = '';
$key .= rawurlencode('tF3CtuDtPGh8OYPBw7ZRs8Mrrj8kjmZRS0Q5jeA1vw'); // Consumer Secret
$key .= '&amp;';
$key .= rawurlencode('FDji1JuBeCNcQzjADjQdN3sOmk7xlAV3ILuooWCuYI'); // Access Token Secret

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, $key, true));
$signature = rawurlencode($signature);

// Construct cURL Headers...

$oauth_header = '';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_consumer_key="'.$oauth_consumer_key.'", '; 
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_nonce="'.$oauth_nonce.'", '; 
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature="'.$oauth_signature.'", '; 
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_timestamp="'.$oauth_timestamp.'", '; 
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_token="'.$oauth_token.'", ';
$oauth_header .= 'oauth_version="1.0", ';

$curl_header = array("Authorization: Oauth {$oauth_header}", 'Expect:');

// Make the cURL Request...

$curl_request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json');
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json = curl_exec($curl_request);
curl_close($curl_request);

$json =  json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah - this is due to Twitter rate limiting for GET favorites/list which allows 15 requests, per 15 minute window, per access token: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits

To overcome this, you will probably want to use a caching solution in your PHP to write the output to a local file and a cron job to request the PHP. This link should help you: http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/jquery-twitter-feed-part2-caching-tweets/